# One to one relationship : ORM

Tags: laravel

I am new to laravel framework and working on one-to-one relationship. I have created a table of student and phone. I am trying to get a student who has a phone number. but i get an error.

[image]

[image]

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Student extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    // protected $table = 'stdnt';

    //protected $primaryKey = 'student_id';
    //public $timestamps = false;

    // One to one relationship
    public function rPhone()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Phone::class);
    }
}
```

---

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Phone extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
}


@foreach ($all_students as $item)
    Name: {{ $item->student_name }} <br>
    Email: {{ $item->student_email }} <br>
    Phone: {{ $item->rPhone->phone }} <br><br>
@endforeach
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of the code but instead provide the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

The error is informing you that the value of `$item->rPhone` is `null`. You can't access properties on a `null` object. This tells you the relationship is failing.

Looking at the screenshots of your database records, you have a `Student` record with an `ID` of `5` but no related record in your `phones` table with a `student_id` of `5` to match. Therefore the relationship doesn't exist and hence a `null` reference.

A simple solution for this is to either create a new record in your `phones` table with a `student_id` of `5` or update an existing record and set the `student_id` to `5`.

Alternatively, you could limit the records you return based on [relationship existance](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) or perform some `null` reference checking in your view when accessing the relationship.

What you could do in your `Blade` view, is make use of the [`optional`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-optional) helper to prevent the error from being thrown. This would also allow you to identify which record(s) are causing the issue.

```
Phone: {{ optional($item->rPhone)->phone }}
```

> After using your modified codes Phone: {{ optional($item->rPhone)->phone }} is now working. But i still dont understand. Kindly explain to me better.

As I have already mentioned and as per the error you're getting, one or more of your `Student` records does not have a related `Phone` record. Which `Student` records are causing the error I can't tell you but using the aforementioned [`optional`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-optional) helper should tell you which as you'll see some of your `@foreach` output missing a `Phone` value.

All the [`optional`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-optional) helper is doing is performing a `null` check on the value you provide it and handling the 'error' gracefully rather than causing an exception to be thrown.

Comment: I have changed to match the student id of 5 to phone related records. but still not working.

Comment: @Palito Are you getting the same error? How and what have you changed? Each `Student` will require a related record in the `phones` table.

Comment: Phone table with student ID matches that of the student table ID.

Comment: @Palito If you're getting the same error message then the same error is present. I have updated my answer to give you another possible solution and means to debug.

Comment: After using your modified codes Phone: {{ optional($item->rPhone)->phone }}  is now working. But i still dont understand. Kindly explain to me better.

Comment: @Palito I have updated my answer to include a 'better' explanation. I really can't simplify it any further.